# git checkout branch but remains in master

Tags: git

I usually switch branch using this command

```
git fetch && git checkout branch
```

After that, I usually check that I'm working on the branch I intended to via `git info`, which would highlight the local branch I'm working on (with an asterisk * next to the branch name).

I followed the same pattern today, but somehow git remains in **master** branch, even after I run `git fetch && git checkout branch`. There are *no error logs* from the command line. But after that, `git info` shows something like this (local branch is still **master**, instead of branch **threads** that I wanted to switch to).

```
    ## Remote Branches:

    origin/HEAD -> origin/master
    origin/master
    origin/threads

    ## Local Branches:

    * master
```

Compare to the normal case (when `git checkout branch` works as expected) - the strange thing seems to be that there are two `origin/master`, the first `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` seems normal; I'm not sure about the second.

There is something weird in here but I haven't figured out.

Comment: Could it be that `git fetch` failed?

Comment: I issued `git fetch` but also no error logs.

Comment: You don't seem to have a local tracking branch for `origin/threads` at all - have you used it before for this specific branch, in this specific repo instance?

Comment: I cloned the repo the first time on this computer. And by default, it would clone master only, I suppose. So yes I don't think the local machine knows about `threads` branch yet, but isn't that what the the `git fetch && git checkout` is for ?

Comment: Did you actually execute `git checkout branch` or `git checkout threads`? Because there is no `origin/branch` to checkout.

Comment: `git checkout threads` is what I exectuted - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can you try to manually create a local tracking branch for `origin/threads` and then check it out? Maybe checkout isn't correctly identifying `orign/threads`. `git branch threads origin/threads && git checkout threads`

Comment: Thanks kostya, Useless, jeremytwfortune for your comments. I worked out that's due to a **diverge master**. I got it work now, but frankly not really sure why I got that diverge master in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I got a diverged master.

Strangely, this command did not shows any error logs.

```
$ git fetch && git checkout threads    # threads is the name of the branch
```

But,

```
    $ git fetch && git checkout master
    Switched to branch 'master'
    Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
    and have 7 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
    (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

and,

```
    $ git pull origin master
    From <git_repo>        # <git_repo> is the URL of the repo
    * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
    Auto-merging <file>    # <file> is the filename in question 
    CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in <file>
    Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

After I manually resolved the conflicts on **master**, now the `git fetch && git checkout threads` works ok, and I can switch to the branch **threads**.

As to why I got a **diverged master** in the first, I'm not sure - perhaps as a result of some `git rebase` command I didn't do properly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `git fetch` will only pull the references as configured in your `.git/config` file - it may not be getting what you expect. If you've not set up a remote tracking branch then it won't know to pull things down from the remote branch.

In addition, 'git checkout master' will always switch to your branch called master, and not what the remote master happens to be. So one you've created a branch called 'master' the above won't change it at all.